# PHP - server outputting garbage - probably encoding issue

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding

Since yesterday, my server is adding some garbage characters to any script in PHP. If I look at my code with view source, I see some spaces and if I display a JSON string, it is considered invalid.

If I take this simple example:

```
<?PHP
echo "hello";
?>
```

It displays hello but in the source code I see a blank line before hello. The encoding of the file is in UTF8 without BOM (did it with Notepad++)

If I use file_get_contents to load the PHP file and then use rawurlencode before outputting the content, I get the following garbage before hello:

```
%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF
```

My first thought was that it was an encoding issue but I checked the concerned PHP file(s) and they are all in UTF8 without BOM. The only solution I have found is to remove this string of garbage each time before treating the content of a file.

I'm using Wordpress and the problem suddenly appeared yesterday while I had not modified any file.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: The secuence code appears to be 3 BOM Characters indicating is UTF-8. if you run that same file on another server/stack do you have the same issue? You need to discard if the issue is on the file or the server. If the issue is on the server, what stack do you have?

Comment: Can you check the existing default encoding set by doing phpinfo()